# Django - template not being detected

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, two-factor-authentication

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/percipient/django-allauth-2fa) to handle two factor auth for a django project, but i'm having some troubles: in my site, i added a **setup.html** page, i set the url on my **urls.py** file but i keep getting this error:

```
In template C:\Users\Us\lib\site-packages\allauth\templates\base.html, error at line 26
    Reverse for 'account_email' not found. 'account_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
    <li><a href="{% url 'account_email' %}">Change E-mail</a></li>
```

Which is completely weird because i'm not trying to load a file called **base.html** but my own **setup.html** file, which is located in my project's folder (the path is **project-folder>templates>setup.html**). This is the **setup.html** that i would like to load from my own templates:

```
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<h1>
  {% trans "Setup Two-Factor Authentication" %}
</h1>

<h4>
  {% trans 'Step 1' %}:
</h4>

<p>
  {% trans 'Scan the QR code below with a token generator of your choice (for instance Google Authenticator).' %}
</p>

<img src="{{ qr_code_url }}" />

<h4>
  {% trans 'Step 2' %}:
</h4>

<p>
  {% trans 'Input a token generated by the app:' %}
</p>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {{ form.token.label }}: {{ form.token }}

  <button type="submit">
    {% trans 'Verify' %}
  </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

It looks like the module that i'm using, instead of loading MY **setup.html** will load something else, but i can't find a way to fix this.

Here is the view that i'm calling to handle the setup (it' the module's view):
https://github.com/percipient/django-allauth-2fa/blob/master/allauth_2fa/views.py

And here is my own **urls.py**, where the view that i mentioned is being called:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.conf.urls import url

from allauth_2fa import views as allauth_2fa_views
app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [

    path("setup/", allauth_2fa_views.TwoFactorSetup.as_view(), name="setup"),

    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TwoFactorSetup` view is using a template *setup.html* in a folder *allauth_2fa*. So all you need to do is place your *setup.html* inside a folder with the same name: *app_folder/templates/allauth_2fa/setup.html* to override it.

Alternatively, subclass `TwoFactorSetup` and just change the `template_name` attribute to point to your template and use that view in your *urls.py*:

```
from allauth_2fa.views import TwoFactorSetup

class MySetup(TwoFactorSetup):
    template_name = 'my_app/setup.html'
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. How can i subclass TwoFactorSetup?

Comment: I tried like this: app_folder/templates/allauth_2fa/setup.html but it will still give the error. Looks like a base.html file is missing apparently

Comment: Are you extending *base.html* in your *setup.html*?

Comment: My bad. I made a typo while creating the folder, it seems to be working now!